# Origin of Mother Boxes in DCEU

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

In Zack Snyder's Justice League (ZSJL),

> younger Darkseid had come to conquer Earth 1000's of years ago, and had lost. He was rescued by his parademons, but the three Mother Boxes were left behind. Now, he has forgotten which world it was that robbed him of his glory.
>
> But in the the present, when Steppenwolf is called by the three Mother Boxes, (or was it just one Mother Box that called him? And if so, then how did he come to know that there were two other boxes on Earth?), how did the New Gods not realise that this was the world that robbed him of his glory? How else would three Mother Boxes be left behind if not for Darkseid having been defeated in the past?

Comment: Someone commented on Reddit about his theory on this, but I am finding it a hard time now to find it:
Mother boxes are scattered throughout the multiverse. When they realise that the world is ripe for invasion "no protectors...", they call out to the New Gods. 
Also, the New Gods tend to take mother boxes with them when they are invading worlds, which is what happened in the history lesson. We might need to ask Zack Snyder on what his head-canon is.

Comment: 1. Of the 3 Mother boxes only the one in Themyscira called out to Steppy, the others were dormant). Although the were dormant, the parademons could "sense" their presence. Steppy says so himself.

Comment: 2. Apokolips is in another universe and it is literally impossible to locate the boxes without knowing where to look for them. Once Superman dies, one box calls out and thus they know the location of the boxes. Armada sent to invade said planet and get the boxes. But Darkseid couldn't be sure that this planet has the ALE, otherwise he would lead said invasion and not send a failing minion.

Comment: 3. Darkseid's parademons left the box in an attempt to save their master from being killed by the Earthlings (and the old Gods). Since there was no one around sensible enough to think about the boxes, they got left behind.

Comment: @Shreedhar 
Thanks for replies. Point 1 and 3, yes, sure.

Point 2: "Apokolips is in another universe... and thus they know the location of the boxes." Yes. 

The parademons only left the boxes behind to save their master. But Darkseid must know this, "Oh I don't know where ALE is. But I know it was that particular planet where I lost a war, and that was the location where I last saw my three mother boxes".

Comment: Darkseid: "So, only if the mother boxes called me, called Apokolips, I would find out ALE in that world."

Comment: They left 3 Mother Boxes on a planet. When they find them, they should think it's the same planet where they left them. They could search any evidence of that, but it should be the first thought they have. Either they left Mother Boxes in more planets (which sounds strange given their purpose), or they lost battles in other planets. Otherwise, their memory isn't good.